# Using Bootstrap with jQuery causes huge memory usage

Tags: jquery, html, debugging, memory, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing a website using simple Bootstrap 3 and jQuery 2

I noticed in Chrome that my page takes more than `400 MB` of Memory after few javascript events being fired (like mouseenter, mouseleave, ... etc)...

Initially the page takes up to `200 MB` as well, which is also not very acceptable.

This is tested on Chrome & Firefox & Safari on Windows, Linux, Mac, and Android...

Can anyone tell answer me:

- What can I use to debug and see details about memory usage (appearently Chrome has no options to show details)...
- What can causes such huge memory consumption.

EDIT:

In Short: I am looking for someway to profile my pages and see what takes the huge amount of memory... 
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's your page causing this memory usage, and not just Chrome itself as its a known memory hog.

Comment: I have tested the page also on Firefox (For Windows and Mac) and tested it on Safari (and monitored the memory usage on mac). I also remotely debugged Chrome on Android and they all shows that my page consumes a very big amount of Memory).

Comment: One reference for finding memory leaks in web applications: https://addyosmani.com/blog/taming-the-unicorn-easing-javascript-memory-profiling-in-devtools/

Answer (score -1):

This question can have many different answers based on different experiences people have. What I would suggest is you have a look at the tutorial written by Chrome team itself here:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network

In a way what I am trying to say is Learn & Find your own answer.

Comment: Thank you, I have already searched a lot, and still investigating the memory consumption caused by jQuery and Bootstrap. That's why there are few alternatives on the web that suggests better solutions... but are still of course limited than jQuery and Bootstrap...